# How to fetch data from object in axios vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuetify.js

This is my code.

```
export default {
 components: {
    draggable,
},
data() {
return {
  ethPrice: null,
 };
},
mounted() {
 axios
  .get(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum&vs_currencies=usd"      
   )
  .then((response) => (this.ethPrice = response.data));
```

And the response is

```
{ "ethereum": { "usd": 2037.4 } }
```

This is the template i did.

```
<v-card-text>{{ ethPrice }}</v-card-text>
```

How I can get inside "ethereum" and then inside "usd" and fetch only the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setup your data like

```
  ethPrice: {ethereum{usd:""}}
```

you need to set it so it remains reactive

`.then((response) => (this.$set(this.ethPrice,response.data)));`

and then access it like

```
{{ethPrice.ethereum.usd}}
```

check the Vue 2 guide on reactivity  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html for a more detailed discussion

Comment: Excuse me, but with your code i got this errors. https://prnt.sc/1amh2lx

Comment: Hi, now it works but I had to skip the reactive `.then((response) => (this.ethPrice = response.data));` and the object declared like this. `ethPrice: { "ethereum": { "usd": "" } }` Thank you!!!